# localhost, production, inetpub and authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have taken on a project which is built in asp.net mvc.
this project is on windows 7 and uses ms visual studio 2012 and its in c#. my experience in the past has been asp.net with vb.net. i also only did desktop applications, no web applications with asp.net.

this new project is a web application. so i am suppose to develop on my local pc, then once i am satisfied with it upload to production.
now my question is, on my local pc, it uses a localhost:"with some port number". it prompts me for a login which i don't know (remember i am taking over someones code). so i can't even by pass testing on localhost before uploading to production, which i am yet to discover whats all about.

i can't even locate my c:/inetpub/wwww

is there a really good website about this that you can suggest?

Comment: Take a look at the MVC tutorials here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials

Comment: The folder 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\' is to your Internet information system. It is designed to host web applications on a local machine. It is found in control panel under Administrative Tools. If that isn't configured app won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it prompts me for a login ,

is it prompts window or just login page, if prompts window that means he's  using windows authentication

just go to the web configration and look for something like that and remove it

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

now if it's login page try search in the data base for user table or something like that , and if he is using asp.net membership in visual studio 2012 select the web project in top menu select project then asp.net configuration option it will open the membership portal search in Google for that .

Comment: its windows authentication since is a window that comes up.